# Method open of object _connection failed

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I am trying to connect to an SQL ce database within Excel. It keeps giving me the:

```
Method Open of object _connection failed
```

Error message whenever it gets to `Conn.Open`.

I've never used ADO before so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Below is my connection script.

```
Sub SQLCeConnect()
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Query As New ADODB.Command
Dim ConnStr As String
Dim RecordSet As New ADODB.RecordSet
Dim i As Integer

'the connection string
ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=X:\ADOTEST\MYDB.sdf;"

'Open ADO Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = ConnStr
Conn.Open
Query.ActiveConnection = Conn
Query.CommandText = "SELECT * From DoorLayers"

Set RecordSet = Query.Execute
RecordSet.Close
Conn.Close
Conn.ConnectionString = ""

Do While Not RecordSet.EOF
    For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print RecordSet.Fields(i).Name, RecordSet.Fields(i).Value
    Next
    RecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
RecordSet.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce

Answer (score 1):

The is usually a bad connection string, but yours looks fine.  The next most common cause is that you don't have the OLEDB provider drivers on your desktop.  You can download it here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5821

Comment: Couldn't figure this out.  I have the oledb provider drivers installed.  I decided to abandon the vba approach.  I am going to simply write vb.net dll and reference it in excel.  Should make things much easier.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing the connection before use it on **WHILE**.
You must close it **after** use the while instruction.